# Category listing.

Tags: category

So I have a categories with sub categories.

```
Anakena (Wine Brand Name)
-Ona (Wine line)

--product one
--product two

-Tama (Wine Line)

--product one
--product two
```

Im trying to make links to the specific lines. So I want to add Anakena under a field, and have it display an ul of Ona, Tama, etc. all the subcategories within Anakena. Once I click on this link, will take me to the category page with all of Ona's produtcs, etc..

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('products').slug('anakena') %}
   <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}<a>
{% endnav %}
```

With this it gives me the main category, Anakena, how can I display the child categories assigned to Anakena.?

Thanks

Comment: Great,! 
Thanks Mats.. One more thing now, Is there a way to replace the .slug name with a user defined something.? each entry will have a different slug, can I have the name filled by an entry.? 

`{% set category = craft.categories.group('products').slug('{{ user defines entry?? }}').first() %}`

Thanks

Comment: Sure, just do `{% set category = craft.categories.group('products').slug(entry.someCustomField) %}`. Don't echo the variable inside the `.slug()` parameter, i.e. don't use `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 1):

By far, the easiest way to do this is to use the [`{% children %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav#showing-children) tag which is available inside a `{% nav %}{% endnav %}` tag pair, i.e. something like this:

```
<ul>
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('products') %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}<a>
      {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
            {% children %}
        </ul>
      {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Note: The above will print a recursive, unordered list of all your top level `product` categories (i.e. "Akana", "Tama" etc) and their children.

In your current code, you won't actually be able to use the `{% children %}`, because you have a `slug('akana')` parameter on your `craft.categories` query for some reason. Using the `slug()` parameter means that Craft will *only pull categories with that particular slug* – in other words, the child category "Ona" won't be returned by your query and the `{% children %}` tag will output nothing.

If you have to use the `slug` parameter, there's no real use to the `{% nav %} tag (it's designed for recursive, hierarchical lists).

For a more "manual" approach, you can also get to a categories children by doing something like this:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('products').slug('akana').first() %}
<a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% set children = category.children %}
{% for child in children %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

One gotcha to note is that `category.children` will pull all your category's children, from all levels. To get children for different levels, you can use the `level` parameter:

```
{% set childrenA = category.children.level(2) %}
{% set childrenB = category.children.level(3) %)
```